# How to write REGEXP to count the number of times a specific pattern is found in a string in MariaDB 10.3

Tags: regex, count, mariadb-10.3

I would like to rewrite the below Oracle REGEXP_COUNT function into MariaDB 10.3. I am trying to rewrite using LENGTH concept but couldn't get valid result.

I am using the `^((((https?|ftps?|gopher|telnet|nntp):\/\/)|(mailto:|news:))(%[0-9A-Fa-f]{2}|[-()_.!~*\'';/?:@&=+$,A-Za-z0-9])+)([).!/?:,][[:blank:]])?$` pattern and the code like this:

```
SET SQL_MODE=ORACLE;
DELIMITER //
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "IS_VALID"(VALUE TEXT) RETURN double
IS
    is_valid DECIMAL (1, 0);
BEGIN
    is_valid := 0;
      IF  REGEXP_COUNT(VALUE, '^((((https?|ftps?|gopher|telnet|nntp):\/\/)|(mailto:|news:))(%[0-9A-Fa-f]{2}|[-()_.!~*\'';/?:@&=+$,A-Za-z0-9])+)([).!/?:,][[:blank:]])?$') = 1
      THEN
        is_valid := 1;
      END IF
    RETURN is_valid;
END;//
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: What do you mean by "confused`? You seem to have a quoting error in the SQL code.

Comment: Well, `'^((((https?|ftps?|gopher|telnet|nntp)://)|(mailto:|news:))(%[0-9A-Fa-f]{2}|[-()_.!~*'';/?:@&=+$,A-Za-z0-9])+)([).!/?:,][[:blank:]])?$'` should work.

Comment: @Wiktor, Yes it worked. The main concern is REGEXP_COUNT. In mariadb we don't have the function REGEXP_COUNT. so please lemme know what is the alternate method to get the count the number of times a specific pattern is found in the string. I even tried using LENGTH concept, but didn't work for me.

Comment: whether REGEXP in MariaDB could suffice the need to count the number of times a specific pattern is found in the string?

Comment: So   why do you say *I am trying to rewrite using REGEXP but couldn't get valid result*? You should update the question with the real problem statement.

Comment: @Wiktor, Sorry I overlooked on that. I have corrected the question part.

Comment: please let me know, does REGEXP helps me to get the valid result.